# bootstrap heaader hiding behind navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**I got the original question below answered but now How can I change the default background color of the nav bar? Down below several answers I asked and put the html and css info.**

Original question: I'm making a website template in html5 and using a Bootstrap navbar. Below the navbar html is the header and the rest of the page content. The header is showing a bit behind the navbar. I checked my html at https://validator.w3.org/nu/ 
and it has no errors. The css in the snippet box below is the **styles.css**

Can anyone figure this out? Thanks.

```css
body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    font-family:'Georgia;
    font-size:100%;
    background-color:#759FAF;
    }
ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
 }
#vlb1overlay {z-index:100 !important;}
#container {
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#fff;    
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
}
#logo {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
 }

#content {
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    padding:1.5em 5%;
 }
#navigation .navbar {

  background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.952941);

  border-radius: 0;

  border-bottom: 0;

  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 0px 3px;

  padding-bottom: 8px;

}



#navigation .navbar-toggle{

  margin-top: 20px;

  background-color: #333;

}



#navigation .navbar-brand h1{

  padding: 0;

  margin: 0;

}



#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li {

 padding: 0 1px;

}



#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right {

 margin-top:28px

}



#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {

 color: #43484E;

 font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;

 font-size: 14px;

 padding: 0;

 text-transform: uppercase;

 -webkit-transition: all .9s ease 0s;

 -moz-transition: all .9s ease 0s;

 -o-transition: all .9s ease 0s;

 transition: all .9s ease 0s;

 padding: 6px 15px;

}



#navigation .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav  .active  a,  

#navigation .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav  .active  a:focus, 

#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li a:hover {

 color: #fff;

 background-color: #fc7700;

}

img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

h1 { 
font-size: 1.7em;
clear: both; 
}
.heading span {
  color: red
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
 }
h3 { 
font-size: 1.2em;
clear: both; }

audio {
    visibility:hidden; 
    height:0; 
    width:0;
 }
#pauseplay {
    float:right; 
    width:32px; 
    height:32px; 
    cursor:pointer;
 }

.innerBox {
  background-color : #ffffff;
  background-repeat : repeat-y;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-bottom : 1em;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.columns {
    width:100%;
}
.left{
    float:left;
    width:45%;    
 }
.right {
    margin-left:45%;
 }
.clear {
    clear:both;
 }
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF TWO  */
.span_2_of_2 {
 width: 100%;
}
.span_1_of_2 {
 width: 49.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col { 
  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span_2_of_2, .span_1_of_2 { width: 100%; }
}
#social {
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}


/* Flexible iFrame */

.Flexible-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.Flexible-container iframe,   
.Flexible-container object,  
.Flexible-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.google-maps {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 75%; // This is the aspect ratio
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.google-maps iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
 }

#footer {
    background:#759FAF;
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:80%;
    color:#fff;
    padding:0.5em 0;
 }
#footer a {
    color:#fff;
 }
/*
  Based on:
  1. http://stephen.io/mediaqueries
  2. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/
*/

/* iPhone 6 in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* 
  iPhone 2G, 3G, 4, 4S Media Queries
  It's noteworthy that these media queries are also the same for iPod Touch generations 1-4.
*/

/* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 2G-4S in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* iPad in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  {
  
}

/* iPad in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPad in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* Galaxy S3 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Galaxy S3 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Galaxy S3 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Galaxy S4 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* Galaxy S4 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Galaxy S4 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Galaxy S5 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* Galaxy S5 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Galaxy S5 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* HTC One portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* HTC One portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* HTC One landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/*
  iPad 3 & 4 Media Queries
  If you're looking to target only 3rd and 4th generation Retina iPads 
  (or tablets with similar resolution) to add @2x graphics,
  or other features for the tablet's Retina display, use the following media queries.
*/

/* Retina iPad in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  
}

/* Retina iPad in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  
}

/* Retina iPad in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  
}

/*
  iPad 1 & 2 Media Queries
  If you're looking to supply different graphics or choose different typography 
  for the lower resolution iPad display, the media queries below will work 
  like a charm in your responsive design!
*/

/* iPad 1 & 2 in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* iPad 1 & 2 in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* iPad 1 & 2 in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* iPad mini in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* iPad mini in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* iPad mini in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* Galaxy Tab 10.1 portrait and landscape */
@media
  (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) {

}

/* Galaxy Tab 10.1 portrait */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 800px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Galaxy Tab 10.1 landscape */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}

/* Asus Nexus 7 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 601px) 
  and (device-height: 906px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) {

}

/* Asus Nexus 7 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 601px) 
  and (device-height: 906px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Asus Nexus 7 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 601px) 
  and (device-height: 906px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 7" portrait and landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 7" portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {
    
}

/* Kindle Fire HD 7" landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 8.9" portrait and landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 8.9" portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {
    
}

/* Kindle Fire HD 8.9" landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Laptops non-retina screens */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    
}

/* Laptops retina screens */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
    
}

/* Apple Watch */
@media
  (max-device-width: 42mm)
  and (min-device-width: 38mm) { 

}

/* Moto 360 Watch */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 218px)
  and (max-device-height: 281px) { 

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="Description" content="">
<meta name="Keywords" content="">
<title>Generic Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main-script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"> 

<div class="container">
  
 <div class="navbar-header">
 <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">My Site</a>

<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse"> 
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 </button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>


        <li class="dropdown">

        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Login<b class="caret"></b></a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>                 

        </ul>


        </li>
     </ul>
 </div>

 </div></div>


        <div id="push"></div>
    


<div id="content">
<h1>HEADER</h1>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

<div id="social"> 
<a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/3D-facebook-64.png" alt="Facebook"></a>&nbsp;
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/3D-email-64.png" alt="email"></a>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<div id="footer"><p>Copyright &copy; <a href=".com/">Generic.com</a></div>
</body></html>
```

[image]

Comment: #content{margin-top:20px}

Answer (score 2):

You are using a fixed header. You will need to add padding to the body element to accomodate the height of the fixed header.

```
body{
  padding-top:65px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Short Answer:

Add this to your CSS to resolve the issue:

```
body {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

## Long Answer:

When you set an element to `position: fixed;` the element is removed from the inline flow, and as such other elements will reflow up to take its place. To resolve this, either a padding or margin will need to be added to the following element (or the body as a whole in this case) of the same height and unit type as the element you set to `fixed` - for this example, setting the body to have `margin-top: 50px;` should resolve the issue.

### Units of Measurement

It's important to pay attention to your unit types: using a differing unit type to achieve the same result could end with unexpected side affects later in development.

For instance, using `body {margin-top: 2em;}` could result in the actual calculated margin changing if you later decided to alter the default font-size of the body.

### Padding VS Margin

While either padding or margin could resolve the issue, using margin is often a better solution, as the proper "top" of the body starts after the navigation bar. This could be important if you were assigning a non-repeating background image to the body, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach with margin

```
body{
   margin-top: 5%; /*Can either be percentage or px whatever suits you*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I used `padding-top:2em;`